# Proof that $|x-a|$ is continuous at $x=a$ (epsilon delta), and nondifferentiable at $x=a$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, continuity

I need help justifying that $|x-a|$ is continuous and non-differentiable at $x=a$. I would also like to prove that it achieves a minimum at $x=a$, but I do not know if that is already clear enough.

Comment: Have you been able to show that $|x-a|$ is continuous at $x=a$?

Comment: I have not by using epsilon delta proof, and I believe that is the method that is desired. I have been able to show it using the limit requirements of continuous functions however

Comment: perhaps this is a difficult choice of function. My goal is to find a function that is continuous at x=a, but not differentiable at x=a, and also f must attain a relative extrema at x=a. The main difficulty comes from finding a function and proving the continuity via epsilon delta proof.

Comment: @Charles I have updated my answer, now it should be complete.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that your function achieves a global minimum at $x=a$, just remark that $|x-a| \geq 0$ for every $x$, and that $|x-a|=0$ when $x=a$. Hence $x=a$ must be, by the very definition, a global minimum of $x \mapsto |x-a|$.

To prove that it is continuous at $x=a$ (all other points are trivially points of continuity), pick $\epsilon>0$. We must show that there exists some $\delta>0$ with the property that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $\left| \left|x-a \right| - \left| a-a \right| \right| < \epsilon$. The last inequality is equivalent to $|x-a|<\epsilon$, so you can choose $\delta=\epsilon$.

To prove that the function is not differentiable at $x=a$, just cremark that
$$
|x-a|=
\begin{cases}
x-a &(x \geq a) \\
a-x &(x<a).
\end{cases}
$$
Hence the left derivative at $x=a$ is $-1$, while the right derivative is $+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity (at any point) follows from the reverse triangle inequality (and this is exactly what you need to produce and $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof):
$$
\left|\,|x-a|-|y-a|\,\right|\leq|(x-a)-(y-a)|=|x-y|.
$$
To see that it is non-differentiable at $a$, you can check that the side derivatives are different:
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{|a+h-a|-|a-a|}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{|h|}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{h}h=1,
$$
while
$$
\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{|a+h-a|-|a-a|}h=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{|h|}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{-h}h=-1.
$$
The minimum is achieved at $x=a$, because $|x-a|\geq0$ for all $x$, and $|a-a|=0$.